# Is there any later version of Bitcoin address generation, than 1?

Tags: address, address-generation

I'm looking for the technical details regarding the format and generation of *Bitcoin* addresses. I've found this article, [“Technical background of **version 1** *Bitcoin* addresses”](https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Technical_background_of_version_1_Bitcoin_addresses), on the *Bitcoin wiki*, but as the title says, it's **version 1**. It seems to be not talking about *the version **prefix*** used in generation of *Bitcoin* addresses.

Is there any later version of it, the method of the generation, such as ***version 2** Bitcoin addresses*?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, there are P2SH addresses, specified in BIP13. They were introduced in 2012 together with the P2SH consensus rule change. They use Base58 version number 5, and are mostly used for multisig constructions (where multiple parties/devices need to sign off on a transaction).

Recently Bech32 addresses were proposed in BIP173, to enable sending to native SegWit addresses. These addresses are easier to read/write, more compact in QR codes, and have better error detection properties. Native SegWit outputs are cheaper to spend and offer a higher security level (disclaimer: I authored BIP173).

Comment: Oh, then there are three versions of it, P2PKH (Pay-to-public-key-hash), P2SH (Pay-to-script-hash), and Bech32, am I right?

Comment: Indeed, though only P2SH and P2PKH are universally supported in software